# bxslider with dynamic html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bxslider

I am using bxslider in a modal and since the modal should present images depending on the user selection, I am writing the html within the slider dynamically.

Here is my modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="figure_carousel" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 80%; height: 100%;">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <br>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">

                <ul class="bxslider" id="elements">



                </ul>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" value="Close" />
            </div>  

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

when an image is clicked I run the following script

```
<script>
    $(document).on("click",".paper_img",function(event){
        var modalview = get_html()
        document.getElementById('elements').innerHTML = ""
        $('#figure_carousel').modal('show');
        $('.bxslider').append(modalview.innerHTML);

        var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({mode: 'horizontal'});
        slider.reloadSlider();
    });
</script>
```

which gets some html (using the get_html function), writes it in the id=elements ul in the modal and launches the modal. Lets assume the html code which comes back from the get_html function looks like this

```
<li><img src="/static/sourcefiles/image.png" alt="figure"/></li>
```

When the modal is opened, the size of the images is wrong. If I resize the browser window manually, the slides become correct. Somehow bxslider cannot deal with me writing html code dynamically. How can I load the bxslider after writing the html code or any other way to solve this?
thanks
carl
EDIT: Here is my problem in an example

http://plnkr.co/edit/sHVq6cggMfVVS4QywQNs?p=preview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your are calling the bxSlider() when the bootstrap modal is hidden. May be the reason bxSlider couldn't detect the height of the images.

```
var bx;
$('#myModal1').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  if(bx === undefined){
    bx= $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
  } else {
    bx.reloadSlider(); 
  }
});
```

`'shown.bs.modal'` it the bootstrap event fires when the model is made visible to user. then we call the bxSlider(), and everytime we add images we are calling bx.reloadSlider();

example : http://plnkr.co/edit/LTMCuDUc3vUm9VnmmvzG?p=preview

Comment: That makes perfect sense, I'm going to see if your code applies to my site as well, thanks PKJ.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
.bx-viewport { min-height: 90vh !important; }
```

---

If that doesn't work or only works once, then try:

**CSS**

```
.bx-viewport.extend { min-height: 90vh !important; }
```

**jQuery**

Add this option:

```
onBeforeSlide: extendVP;
```

Add this to above the `</body>` end tag:

```
function extendVP($ele, from, to) {
     var vp = $('.bx-viewport');
     vp.addClass('extend');
}
```

---

**UPDATE 1**

If images are not scaling with the proper aspect ratio or not even scaling, here's 2 suggestions:

**CSS**

Simple

```
img { width: 100%; height: auto; }
```

Better

This procedure involves using a background image:

1. Place a `<div>` in a slide (`<li>` for your markup), give it a `class` (like `imgFrame`)
2. Then place an inline `style` attribute on it. Assign the image to `imgFrame` as follows:

   - `<div class="imgFrame" style="background-image: url('path/to/img.jpg')"></div>`
3. Next add this to your CSS:

   - `.imgFrame {
         width: 100%;
         height: auto;
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         background-size: contain;
      }`

---

**UPDATE 2**

The modifications done to this bxSlider demo is not to show it works, because it doesn't have the height issue in the first place. It's purpose is to show the source and explain what it does. While making this demo, I created a function `adaptiveWidth()`, it's optional. What it does is on page load it has an overlay, once it's clicked, it'll enter full screen mode then quickly exit full screen as the overlay fades away. Hopefully that'll *wake up* bxSlider from it's stupor.

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/01/pen/yYGmwo)

**CSS**

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

/* Default Style ____________________________________________________*/

html, body { box-sizing: border-box; }
html { height: 100vh; width: 100vw; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; }
body { height: 100%; width: 100%; position: relative; }
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; }

/* Aesthetics [Optional]_____________________________________________*/

html { font: 400 16px/1.45 'Source Code Pro'; }
body { background: #000; color: #FFF; font-variant: small-caps; }
h1 { font-size: 3rem; font-weight: 700; }

/* jquery.bxslider.css jsDelvr.com Image Override ___________________*/

.bx-wrapper .bx-loading { background: url('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/images/bx_loader.gif') center center no-repeat #ffffff; }
.bx-wrapper .bx-prev { background: url('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/images/controls.png') no-repeat 0 -32px; }
.bx-wrapper .bx-next { background: url('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/images/controls.png') no-repeat -43px -32px; }
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start { background: url('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/images/controls.png') -86px -11px no-repeat; }
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop { background: url('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/images/controls.png') -86px -44px no-repeat; }

/* bxSlider init Style ___________________________________________*/

#overlay { position: fixed; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; z-index: 999999999; height: 101%; width: 101%; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer; pointer-events: auto; background-color: black; opacity: .5; }
.ext { max-width: -moz-fit-content; max-width: -webkit-fit-content; max-width: fit-content; width: auto; height: auto; padding: 25%; } /* adaptiveWidth Style [Optional] */
```

**HTML**

```
<body class="expand">
<div id="overlay"><h1>Click anywhere to start</h1></div>
<div class="ext"> <!-- adaptiveWidth Wrapper [Optional] -->
<ul class='bxslider'>
    <li>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/500X16:9/000/FFF.png&text=1"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/500X4:3/07C/FC0.png&text=2"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/4:3X400/D06/0FF.png&text=3"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/640X16:9/765/cee.png&text=4"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/210X16:9/B40/6F3.png&text=5"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/16:9X420/E2F/FC9.png&text=6"/>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**jQ/JS**

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> 
<!-- [Suggestion] Don't use the minified version: jquery.bxslider.min.js, it's buggy -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.js"></script> 

/* Page loads #overlay */
$(document).ready(function() {                      // jQ DocReady
    $("#overlay").one('click', function(event) {    // User  clicks #overlay
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();           // Isolate Event
        var tgt = document.querySelector('.expand'),// Target <body>
                that = this;                // Establish this as that
        enterFS(tgt);                       // Enter full screen to wakeup bxSlider!
        exitFS();                                  // Exit full screen
            $(that).fadeOut(1000, function() {     // #overlay fades...
                $(that).remove();                  // #overlay is gone
        });
    });
    /* Adaptive bxSlider */ 
    var bx = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        adaptiveHeight: true,   // http://bxslider.com/options#adaptiveHeight
        onSlideBefore: adaptiveWidth    // Callback [optional]
    });
});

/* adaptiveHeight [Optional] */
function adaptiveWidth($ele, from, to) {
    var imgWidth = $ele.find('img').width();
    var bxWidth = $('.bx-wrapper').width(imgWidth);
}

/* Enter Full Screen */ 
function enterFS(element) {
    if(element.requestFullscreen) {
        element.requestFullscreen();
    } 
    else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } 
    else if(element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } 
    else if(element.msRequestFullscreen) {
        element.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
}

/* Exit Full Screen */
function exitFS() {
    if(document.exitFullscreen) {
        document.exitFullscreen();
    } 
    else if(document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } 
    else if(document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
        document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    }
}
```

Comment: hi zer... thanks for the suggestion. Your suggestion changes the height of the bxslider, but it does not solve the problem of the images having the wrong size... cheers

Comment: @carl How did you set the width of your images?

Comment: I did not set anything?

Comment: this still doesn't work... I don't think it has anything to do with the images being the wrong size. As soon as I resize the browser the images are displayed correctly. It must have to do with something bxslider updates when the browser is resized...

Comment: I just had a simular problem a couple of days ago and yes the images were not my problem either.  Adjusting the viewport solved half the problem and the other half may not be applicable to your situation (I'm front-end and the back-end is halfway across the world.) I fixed it 2 ways and the first solution may work for you. Standby for an update...

Comment: sorry but it is still not working... have a look to the jsfiddle I included above

Comment: The jsFiddle has none of my suggestions, or is there another jsFiddle I overlooked?

Comment: no I just added the fiddle to explain my original problem. I tried your solutions in my code, but it did not work. I also do not quite understand your solution, so I though the fiddle might be a better way to deal with this. E.g. the fact that you give the body a class (expand) and later you modify this class has very strange effects on my browser.

Comment: I'm transferring your demo to plunkr and correcting it: #-- innerhtml should be innerHTML #-- The `link` and `script` tags pointing to the bootstrap-select files are dead #-- The instantiation of bxSlider isn't wrapped inside of a jQuery docReady. I must change the implementation of this demo because the modal is tricky.

Comment: @carl this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/sHVq6cggMfVVS4QywQNs?p=preview) is version 1. Version 1 is the syntactically correct original demo.

Comment: hi zer... I am sorry, the jsfiddle worked for me but I noticed that when clicking on the link above the fiddle doesn't work anymore... thanks for the plunkr version

Comment: The versions can fool you if you loose track on updating as you work on them, no worries. Is there any problems using iframes with your service? Take a look at this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/mwqfgaom/1/). It's 6 horizontal bxSliders inside a vertical bxSlider using 6 iframes. Iframes are great for running complex JS on a WordPress, CMS, Bootstrapped sites because they're isolated.